# Can print out value, but in setState its "undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have form that send its value to a function:

```
 _onChange(ev, option) {

    console.log(option.key)  // option.key = 3

    this.setState({ dropdownValue:option.key })  // option key = "undefined"
 }
```

As you can see above, I can print out the value, for example 3. However, when I try to add it to the state directly afterward I get an error "cannot set state of undefined".

i have tried to add the value to a variable and then use that to setState but I still get that error. How come?

My onChange method:

```
<ChoiceGroup
                            className="defaultChoiceGroup"
                            defaultSelectedKey="B"
                            options={[
                                {
                                    key: '1',
                                    text: 'test'
                                },
                                {
                                    key: '2',
                                    text: 'test2'
                                },
                                {
                                    key: '3',
                                    text: 'test3',

                                }
                            ]}
                            onChange={this._onChange }
                            label="Change password for..."
                            required={true}
                        />
```

Comment: Can you include the code that calls `_onChange`?

Comment: Yes, I have added the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure 'cannot set state of undefined' is the exact error you're getting? I'm assuming here that `this` is undefined because your function is not binded to `this`. To resolve this you can either bind it manually or use an arrow function. I'd suggest going for an arrow function:

```
_onChange = (ev, option) => {
    console.log(option.key)  // option.key = 3

    this.setState({ dropdownValue:option.key })  // option key = "undefined"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the function to the context. The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

Add this to the constructor.

```
this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this)
```

1. https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html